# iPad's splitViewController returns null

Tags: ipad, null, uisplitviewcontroller

I have this code,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;
    if (row == 0) {
        FirstDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailView" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
    }

    if (row == 1) {
        SecondDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailView" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
    }

    if (row == 2) {
        view31 *newDetailViewController = [[view31 alloc] initWithNibName:@"view31" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = newDetailViewController;

        NSLog(@"%@", detailViewController);
    }

    // Update the split view controller's view controllers array.

    NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController , detailViewController, nil];

    // NSArray *newVCs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0], viewControllers, nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", viewControllers);

    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.splitViewController.viewControllers);

    [viewControllers release];

    // Dismiss the popover if it's present.
    if (popoverController != nil) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

    // Configure the new view controller's popover button (after the view has been displayed and its toolbar/navigation bar has been created).
    if (rootPopoverButtonItem != nil) {
        [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:self.rootPopoverButtonItem];
    }

    [detailViewController release];
}
```

Why does `self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;` return null?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the value of detailViewController the moment you add it to your viewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem...
well... I think you don't see any viewControllers there, because this method is only called when the user is tapping on one of the rows in the rootviewcontroller. Only then will be an assignment of a detailviewcontroller to the array.

So if you tap on a view controller, you will have a reassignment of the array property.

Right now it is interesting, because when I am loading that file, I have no viewcontrollers assigned to that splitview controllers array as well.